# React this is not defined inside a child state iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to make the state of the parent change on the child, I have a list of peoples, and I have made a iteration using Object.keys, and I need that in every iteration a button appears and handles the "add friend" function from the parent.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class People extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    let friends = this.props.userData;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="title">
          <h1>People You might know</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            {Object.keys(friends).map(function (key) {
              var friend = friends[key];
              return (<div className="userData">
                <img src={friend.profilePic} className="profile-photo" alt="userPhoto" />

                <div className="data" id="name">
                  {friend.name}
                  <br />
                  <div className="city">
                    Ciudad: {friend.city}
                  </div>
                </div>

                {/* this is the one that isnt working */}
                <button onClick={this.props.addFriend}>Add as a friend</button>   
              </div>);
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}

export default People;
```

this is the parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Profile from './profile';
import People from './people';
import Photo from './meSmall.jpg';
import FriendList from './friendList';
import './App.css';
import './profile.css';
import './people.css';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userData: {
         name: "User1",
         city: "city2",
         profilePic: Photo    
      },
      friendList:{

      },
      peopleList:{
        f1:{
         name: "Maria",
         city: "city3",
         profilePic: "./images/f1.jpg",  
        },
        f2:{
         name: "James",
         city: "city4",
         profilePic: "./images/f2.jpg"       
        }  
     }            
  }
        this.handleAddFriend = this.handleAddFriend.bind(this);

}

 render(){
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <div className="profile">
         <Profile userData={this.state.userData}/>
      </div>  
    <div>
      <FriendList friendList = {this.state.friendList}/>
   </div>      
     <div className="people">
       <People userData = {this.state.peopleList} addFriend={this.handleAddFriend}/>
    </div>         
</div>
);    
}

handleAddFriend(){
  this.setState({
  friendList:{
    f1:{
       name: "Maria Almagro",
       city: "Cordoba",
       profilePic: "./images/f1.jpg",  
    },
    f2:{
      name: "Pablo Gramajo",
      city: "Cafayate",
      profilePic: "./images/f2.jpg"       
    }
   }
  })
 }
}

export default App;
```

If I don't put the onClick and the function, or put the button outside the Object.keys (the function works well), the page displays as I want, but I need to add a button to every people in the list, for the moment I'm only using a static state with the people data.
I get TypeError: this is undefined. How can I make it?

Comment: *make the state of the parent change on the child*. You really should do the opposite. Nice to read: https://chenglou.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to solve your onClick issue is to use `arrow function`
in the `map` method

**Like this**

```js
{Object.keys(friends).map((key) => { ...
```

Instead of using `function` like this

```js
{Object.keys(friends).map(function(key) { ...
```

I have copied your code and have tested on my local. It works.

**With arrow function:**

- They don't create their own `this`, thus the enclosing `this` is being used.
- `this` simply refers to the values of `this` in the environment the arrow function is defined in (i.e. "outside" the arrow function) and that remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of `this` in the closest non-arrow parent function

Answer (score 0):

you need ()=> and .bind(this) to use parent functions refering to their this inside child components

```
onClick={() => this.props.addFriend.bind(this)}
```

Comment: I'm using this onClick={ () => this.props.addFriend.bind(this) } but it doesnt work when I click.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to bind every handler you have or use arrow functions. I prefer arrow functions . So you need to update the following;

Convert all functions to arrow functions starting from handleAddFriend;

```
const handleAddFriend = (friend) => {
  // TODO: set the input friend here
  console.log('hey you triggered handleAddFriend with; ', friend);
  this.setState({
...
...
};
```

now you can use it in the child component as below;

```
...
 <button onClick={() => this.props.addFriend(friend);}>Add as a friend</button> 
...
```

Comment: Great, now it renders, but on click, I get the same error

Comment: could you share the parent component?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: @Soul7aker Updated my answer

Comment: I'm getting an Unexpected token in the arrow function const handleAddFriend